# How to refactor this polymorphic URL helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism

I have the following ugly helper method which determines the URL for a given activity. In all but 1 case the path generates a link to a question with an anchor (Stack Overflow style), which is retrieved by a series of tenuous `if/else` statements, accessing whether the trackable object is a comment or an answer then assigning the result to a variable which is passed into a url_for helper at the end.

I have 2 questions regarding this situation:

1. The current implementation feels like the wrong approach. Should I determine these paths when the activity is saved and capture the path to the DB so I don't have to generate these paths each time the user visits the path? Or is there a more railsy way of dealing with this?
2. If this is the right avenue to go down or something similar, firstly, how can I refactor this into something more succinct, and should this be a class method or a helper method as its only dealing with an activity's path?

activity_helper.rb

```
def get_activity_path(activity)
  if activity.trackable_type == "Comment"
    object = a.trackable.commentable_type == "Question" ? a.trackable.commentable : a.trackable.commentable.question
  elsif activity.trackable_type == "Answer"
    object = activity.trackable.question
  end
  activity.trackable_type == "User" ? info_path : "#{url_for(object)}##{activity.trackable_type.downcase}_#{activity.trackable.id}"
end
```

Associations

```
class Answer
  belongs_to :question, counter_cache: true
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :activities, as: :trackable, dependent: :destroy

class Comment
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :activities, as: :trackable, dependent: :destroy

class Question
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
```

I'm using rails 3.2.14, ruby 1.9.3p448 and the public_activity gem - https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity. 
If anyone needs more code just shout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use polymoprhic url - just pass to `link_to` model as second parameter and that's it. But it 2x slower than helper method way. So it's up to you leave this ugly code or use polymorphic url. Check out [this post](http://railsguides.net/2013/12/04/rails-url-for-helper-can-be-slow/) which suggests what to use and where.

Comment: Good point about the speed, whilst it may be slightly cleaner perhaps it's not worth the performance loss.